# How to use alpha in unity unlit graph for particle system without make it disappear?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, particle-system, shader-graph

[image]

Howdy Guys !
I'm using the unity's graph system , but when I take the Alpha from split and connect it to the Unlit Master's Alpha , the preview dissapear and when i add it to particle system as a shader , nothing works !!!!
What is the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout the [`AlphaClipThreshold`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.shadergraph@6.9/manual/Unlit-Master-Node.html)

> Fragments with an alpha below this value will be discarded.

Yours is set to `1` which means anything lower then `1` will be clipped of, so since your alpha moves in a range `0` to `< 1` basically "everything" ;)

Comment: So what do U think I should do ??

Comment: Reduce the `AlphaClipThreshold`